# force close when clicking menu item android

Tags: android, forceclose, rate

I have a menu inflator with 2 options, About, and Rate. About works just fine, when rate is clicked, it force closes.

```
    case R.id.About:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.Rate:
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
               Uri.parse("market://details?
                     id="+"com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"));
        startActivity(marketIntent);
            }
```

and the manifest code

```
<activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.About"/>
    <activity android:name="com.androidsleepmachine.gamble.Rate" />
```

and the Logcat

```
06-13 23:59:30.294: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-13 23:59:30.294: E/AndroidRuntime(1576): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:   
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW 
dat=market://details?id=com.androidsleepmachine.gamble }
```

I am sure it is something simple that I have overlooked but it is driving me insane. Again, About works just fine, Rate causes a force close instead of loading the marketplace URL to my app so the user can rate it.

Comment: Is this on an emulator or device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the device or emulator where you're running this code doesn't have the *Play Store* app installed. When you try to start an Intent for which there is no valid filter in the system, you will get these exceptions.

An alternative would be to verify this (via `PackageManager`) before trying to start the intent. If no activity matches, then use the web URI (i.e. `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>`) instead.

```
List<ResolveInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(marketIntent, 0);
if (apps.size() != 0)
   <use market intent>
else
   <use http intent>
```

(Or, a bit cruder but simpler, catch `ActivityNotFoundException` and do the same).

Comment: I just noiced there is no play store app on the emulator. I will try to load the app on a device tomorrow and run it again. Thank you

Comment: @user2727048 Yes, that was the most likely explanation :) Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you'd want to do to make sure it works even if there's no Play Store:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); 

try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

This'll launch the browser if Play Store App is not installed.